# Troubling linking stylesheets in webpage, directory related issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'll try to make this simple since its such a beginner question, I currently have an index.html page which is working perfectly, picture this working code:

**example > index.html**

However my stylesheets are found in (example):

**example > assets > plugins > bootstrap > css > bootstrap.min**

The code I used was:

```
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This worked perfectly, now I have another page which is in:

**example > pages > features.html**

You've probably noticed that the 'pages' and 'assets' folders are in the same directory, so I decided to link them with this code:

```
<link href="../../example/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

However none of the stylesheets and plugins are linking to the page, looking for a quick problem solver for this one, tried all kinds of fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving from the example folder. This works:

```
<link href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you it semi-worked but now I have a different problem, i'll make a new post! thank you